# Coloring rows problem

Tags: tables, multirow, rowcolor

I need fill table rows with color, but I have few problem with it:

1. If I do this some columns are overlaid by background (first pic - multirow).
2. I see white borders. (I don't understand why - they should be here)
3. I do not know how I can set color for columns at right side table (mirrored L) on "none" or "white".

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I need:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{geometry}                 % customize page layout
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}                 % multirow for table (rowspan)

\geometry{paper=a4paper, landscape,hmargin=28.5mm,vmargin=20mm}

\setlength\parindent{0cm}   % no indent for whole document
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0cm}   % padding either side of each column (only horizontal)

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

% document start
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\columncolor{Gray}\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\columncolor{Gray}\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}

\newcolumntype{X}[1]{>{\columncolor{Gray}\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\columncolor{Gray}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}


  \begin{tabular}{
  | P{1.4cm}
  | M{1.4cm}
  | M{1.4cm}
  | P{7.6cm}
  | P{6.4cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{2.2cm}
  |
}

\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\rule[-0.4cm]{0cm}{1cm} B} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{q} \\

\hline
a & SSW \par \footnotesize{(xx)} & xxx \footnotesize{(xxx)} & b & & x & d & e &  \\\cline{1-8}

\rule[-0.8cm]{0cm}{1cm} & & &
\multirow{8}{7.6cm}{%
\rule[-.4cm]{0.5cm}{0cm}
  \begin{tabular}{
   X{2.5cm}
   X{0.9cm}
   Y{1.6cm}
   Y{1.6cm}
}
one question & & $\bigcirc$ yes & $\bigcirc$ no \\
second question & & $\bigcirc$ left & $\bigcirc$ right \\
third question & & $\bigcirc$ yes & $\bigcirc$ no \\
fourth question & & $\bigcirc$ yes & $\bigcirc$ no \\
fifth question & & $\bigcirc$ yes & $\bigcirc$ no \\
sixsth question & & $\bigcirc$ mono & $\bigcirc$ color \\
\end{tabular} %
}
  & & & & & \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-8}
\rule[-0.8cm]{0cm}{1cm} & & & & & & & & \\\cline{1-3}\cline{5-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|P{2.8cm}}{\rule{0cm}{1cm}}  & & & & \multicolumn{3}{P{2.8cm}}{\rule{0cm}{1cm}}  &\\
\hline

\end{tabular}

% document end
\end{document}
```

Comment: So you don't need the first row (with B and q)?

Comment: no... thx - updated

Comment: Why are you nesting tabulars?

Comment: Because i want alignment columns in responses.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes about your code and also the changes:

- Loading `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` also loads `colortbl`.
- You can load `\usepackage{array, multirow}` together (saves one line!).
- New column types should be defined here
- Remember that the paper format is loaded in the document class and you can apply the margins and the landscape as options of the `geometry` package.

As a personal note, I suggest you load all the packages together, then all the various tweaks in the preamble and then the document. It's not a rule, but it's better organised. It's up to your preference, though.

I loaded the `hhline` package for coloring the rules, then used `\rowcolors{2}{Gray}{Gray}` for the rows, and the command `\cellcolor{white}` to isolate the white cells (except the top). There is no need to nest tabulars, my solution uses one tabular only.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=28.5mm,vmargin=20mm,landscape]{geometry} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array, multirow}                 % multirow for table (rowspan)

\setlength\parindent{0cm}   % no indent for whole document
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0cm}   % padding either side of each column (only horizontal)

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}

\newcolumntype{X}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\hspace{2pt}\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\newcommand{\myl}{%
\hhline{*3{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-}*4{>{\arrayrulecolor[gray]{.85}}-}|*3{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}-}}
}

\begin{document}
    \rowcolors{2}{Gray}{Gray}
\begin{tabular}{|P{1.4cm}|M{1.4cm}|M{1.3cm}|Y{4cm}Y{1.5cm}Y{1.5cm}|P{7.6cm}|P{1.2cm}|P{1.2cm}|P{1.2cm}|P{2.2cm}|
}
\hline
\rowcolor{white}
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{B} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{q} \\ \hline
a   & SSW \par \footnotesize{(xx)} & xxx \footnotesize{(xxx)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{b} & & x & d & e & \cellcolor{white} \\ \hhline{*{10}{-}}
    & & & one question & $\bigcirc$ yes & $\bigcirc$ no & & & & & \cellcolor{white} \\ \myl
    & & & second question & $\bigcirc$ left & $\bigcirc$ right & & & & & \cellcolor{white} \\ \myl
    & & & third question & $\bigcirc$ yes & $\bigcirc$ no & & & & & \cellcolor{white} \\ \myl
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & fourth question & $\bigcirc$ yes & $\bigcirc$ no & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{white}} & \cellcolor{white} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & fourth question & $\bigcirc$ yes & $\bigcirc$ no & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{white}} & \cellcolor{white} \\
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{}} & sixth question & $\bigcirc$ mono & $\bigcirc$ color & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor{white}}} & \cellcolor{white} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yeah thx but there is still white lines and table looks different now (in multicolumn where are questions is not padding and there is too big line height)

Comment: @LajdákMarek You can try adding a negative vertical skip, but as far as I know there is currently no universal solution to this. Coloured tables usually display those thin white lines. I'm looking into it, though.